# 2 questions about drag and drop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to be able to drag random highlighted text or images on a random page that is not written by me, thus I cannot simply wrap the text in a div and make it draggable.

Is there any way to get highlighted text or images on a random page, like say Yahoo, and drop it into a container that can recognize what was being dropped into it (like content and content-type) without it even being an explicitly declared draggable?

I've been playing with jQuery, but can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
David

Comment: The EverNote bookmarklet does this (http://www.evernote.com/about/download/). You could try digging into their source code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Directly no, but I wonder if it's possible to copy element and then make it droppable?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

That's exactly what I tried, but I think my approach is slightly off. Maybe you can take a look at it? This is what I did.

http://pastie.org/541937

Comment: This is what scriptaculous does if you enable ghosting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)? There are some [demos](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/demos). It uses prototype rather than jquery though...